# how to provide Jelly bean support to android kitkat app

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have made an android app, `minSdkVersion = 19` and `targetSdkVersion =19`.
I have targetted it for devices having kitkat .Now i want to add Jelly Beans support to it . Right Now when i try to install my app on any jelly bean device it says:

`"No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD."`

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: So then you need to make the app for an older version of the SDK. JellyBean is from SdkVersion 16, so you'd definitely need to recompile the app for minSdkVersion=16 at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using android studio

go to you're app gradle and change

`defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }`

and if you're using eclipse in you're manifest file change this

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"
          android:targetSdkVersion="23"
          android:maxSdkVersion="23" />`

Comment: Is `maxSdkVersion` really needed here? I doubt that it's a good idea to restrict your app to a maximum SDK version in any case.

Comment: no i added it as it is so that he can relate to the code

Comment: i have specified minSdkVersion = 16 and targetSdkVersion = 19. I have also installed Sdk Platfrom for API levels 16 to 19 . i.e 16, 17,19.
But still when i try to install my app on the jelly bean device it says :-"No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD."

Comment: I think i found the reason. Its happening because i need to change the android project properties and need to specify the target Api level as 16.
In eclipse i did, Project > Properties > Android > Select API level to 16 and Apply.
Although its giving many errors when i build now . But those are valild errors as some xml properties i am using currently are not there in API level 16.